# Refresh and ValidityCheck operations in the SEAL Code

Tags: seal

While reading the [Homomorphic Encryption Standard](https://projects.csail.mit.edu/HEWorkshop/HomomorphicEncryptionStandard2018.pdf) I came across those two operations:

1. Refresh(Params, flag, EK, C1) → C2.
2. ValidityCheck(Params, EK, [C], COMP) → flag.

I've searched their implementation in the SEAL Code but couldn’t find any, although I think that the first one is only implemented as `evaluator.relinearize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct. SEAL 2.3.1 only implements the flag="Relinearize" variant of the Refresh operation. ValidityCheck is not implemented in SEAL 2.3.1 at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why ValidityCheck is not implemented? One could use it to detect Problems, when for example the noise count of a `Ciphertext` goes under some predefined threshold.

Comment: What can create future Problems with executing operations on that `Ciphertext`.

Comment: There is no particular reason for ValidityCheck not being implemented. Doing it "right" requires some non-trivial machinery that is not currently in SEAL but will probably be in the future once developer tools for homomorphic encryption get more mature.